# Unable to install ubuntu 13.10 on dell xps 15 L502X.. operating system not found

Tags: dell

I have windows 8 installed on my laptop.
I own a dell XPS 15 L502X laptop.
I am trying to install ubuntu using USB but whenever I try rebooting my laptop to start the installation, There's an error "OPERATING SYSTEM NOT FOUND". Laptop is unable to find OS on my USB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you create the USB?

Comment: You might have to enable USB booting in the bios. Do you see the USB device when booting up?

Comment: Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a USB universal installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ Maybe you dont have a bootable pendrive.
Check if you change in bios to boot by removable devices first